# Why does it say "(x) days left to add coverage"?

Tags: macbook-pro, applecare

Whilst looking at my "support" tab in About My Mac, it says I have "23 days left to add coverage". What does this mean? Will I be unable to add coverage if it gets past those 23 days? The computer is a relatively new purchase and I recall something like 60 days as the maximum value I'd seen there.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want AppleCare, call Apple tomorrow to be sure the dates are correct. In the past you had no ability to extend it, to pay monthly, or to get a custom length.

All that has changed in many but not all purchasing geographic regions. Apple is letting you know by their records you’re about to get locked out of the option to extend or renew coverage.

If their records are correct, you’ve got 23 days to decide, but I’ve seen their systems fail in the past. Better to talk with them and make a decision now so you can renew. Ask them about cancellation options, too so you are an informed purchaser.